# WPF привязка коллекции к ComboBox.ItemsSource

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Код XAML:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ProductTypesList}" SelectedItem="{Binding  CurrentProduct.ProductType}"/>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class EditProductViewModel : StoreUsingViewModel
{
    private ProductModel currentProduct;
    public ProductModel CurrentProduct
    { 
      get {return currentProduct;}
      set {currentProduct = value; OnPropertyChanged("CurrentProduct")}
    }
    public ObservableCollection<ProductTypeModel> ProductTypesList {get;set;}

    public EditProductViewModel()
    {
        ProductTypesList = new ObservableCollection<ProductTypeModel>();
        Store
            .Get<ProductType>()
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(p => ProductTypesList.Add(new ProductTypeModel(p)));
    }
//событие из другой VM(со списком продуктов) передаёт инстанс ProductModel, который нужно редактировать в этой VM. Код обработчика события из мессенджера:
    [EventSubscription("EditCommandExecuted", typeof(OnPublisher))]
    public void EditCommandExecutedEventHandler(object sender, EditEventArgs e)
    {
             this.CurrentProduct = e.ProductModelInstance;
    }
}
```

После вызова метода `EditCommandExecutedEventHandler(object sender, EditEventArgs e)`  , на экране пользователя выводится UserControl, привязанный к описанной VM (XAML-код контрола представлен в начале вопроса). Когда запускаю приложение, и на экран выводится View, в ComboBox присутствует коллекция элементов из ProductTypesList, но, несмотря на то, что `SelectedItem="CurrentProduct.ProductType"`, нужный ProductType в ComboBox'e не выводится. В чём загвоздка?

*PS: Product, ProductType - модели EF, ProductModel, ProductTypeModel - модели MVVM. Конструктор ProductModel принимает в качестве аргумента инстанс Product'a.*

Comment: Чуть позже оформлю в виде ответа. Вам нужно биндиться к SelectedIndex, и выставлять этот индекс вручную. Дело в том, что установив SelectedItem со стороны модели, вы просто меняете значение SelectedItem, но контрол не настолько умный, чтобы искать его по коллекции и менять SelectedIndex.

Comment: [Binding ComboBox SelectedItem using MVVM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19632270/binding-combobox-selecteditem-using-mvvm)

Comment: @AntonPapin на самом деле - умный, но скорее всего у автора экземпляр класса `CurrentProduct.ProductType` не входит в коллекцию `ProductTypesList`.

Comment: @Monk, в этом и суть, я просто не совсем однозначно выразился - если установить в качестве `SelectedItem` объект, не принадлежащий `ItemsSource`, то `SelectedIndex` не изменится.

Comment: Господа, кажется, можно сделать так: `<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ProductTypesList}" 
          SelectedValue="{Binding CurrentProduct.ProductType.UID, Mode=TwoWay}" 
          SelectedValuePath="UID" 
          DisplayMemberPath="Name" />`

Comment: Это решение вопроса в вашем случае, но это выглядит некорректным решением со стороны MVVM. В любом случае - главное чтобы оно работало. Если работает и  вас устраивает - по возможности оформите ответ самостоятельно.

Comment: @Monk, оформлю несколько позже. Не могли бы Вы пояснить, почему  считаете, что это идёт в разрез с принципами MVVM?

Comment: Потому что у вас есть вьюмодель, которая противоречит сама себе, когда содержимое коллекции не содержит выбранный элемент. Это как говорить, что я выбираю N, когда мне дали выбор из A,B,C.

Comment: @Monk, так и в чём здесь противоречивость VM? Тогда скажите, что делать в случае, если у меня в VM десять таких коллекций, и каждая должна содержать ссылку на один и тот же объект ("содержать этот объект")?

Comment: @Monk `this.CurrentProduct = ProductTypesList.Single(p => p.Id == e.ProductModelInstance.Id);` - код из вашего ответа. Вы здесь пытаетесь сравнить Id объектов разных типов. Возможно, Вы недостаточно внимательно прочитали мой код. Но, в любом случае, спасибо за попытку помочь:)

Answer (score 1):

А если попробовать вместо

```
this.CurrentProduct = e.ProductModelInstance;
```

сделать

```
this.CurrentProduct = ProductTypesList.Single(p => p.Id == e.ProductModelInstance.Id);
```

биндинг работает?

Comment: ProductTypesList не содержит вложенных коллекций в себе, выкинет NullReferenceException. Дело ещё в том, что у меня в ProductModel содержится ещё с десяток различных свойств с типами, ProductManufacturerModel, PdoductSummaryModel и т.п. Не понимаю, как это всё корректно связать.

Comment: И да, Вы правы, `CurrentProduct.ProductType` не входит в коллекцию `ProductTypesList`.

Comment: `ProductTypesList` - сам коллекция, не должен он кидать `NRE`. А вот то, что выбранный элемент не входит в коллекцию - так как вы себе представляете выбор из того, чего нет?

Comment: при помощи комбинации SelectedValue и SelectedValuePath, ссылаясь на ID элементов.

Comment: @klutch1991 похоже на костыли, но если работает - ура.

Comment: "...Let's also say you have a CategoryID property on that Product object, and you want the user to be able to select a category for the product from a list of categories. You need the ID property of the Category object to be assigned to the CategoryID property on the Product object. This is where the SelectedValuePath and the SelectedValue properties come in." - Chris Anderson

Answer (score 0):

Вы забыли Binding

`SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentProduct.ProductType}"/>`

Comment: Извиняюсь, это опечатка. На самом деле Binding там есть.

Comment: Бывает, что у автора проблемы с составлением вопроса, в этих случаях очевидные ответы могут не иметь отношения к реальной проблеме. [Соображения по теме](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/2297/%D0%98%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5/2299#2299).